# Problems referencing primary key with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, ssms

This is code to create the beginnings of a book library database with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

```
CREATE DATABASE BOOK_LIBRARY

CREATE TABLE LIBRARY_USER
(
    usr_id int not null primary key,
    f_name varchar(30) not null,
    m_init char(1),
    l_name varchar(30) not null,
    balance decimal(6,2),
    join_date date,
    addrss_1 varchar(30) not null,
    addrss_2 varchar(30),
    city varchar(30) not null,
    addrss_state char(2) not null,
    zip_code varchar(10) not null,
    email varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE LIBRARY_TRANSACTIONS
(
    transaction_id int not null primary key,
    maximum_borrow_duration int not null,
    strt_date date not null,
    actual_return_date date not null,
    borrow_usr_id int not null,
    foreign key (borrow_usr_id) references LIBRARY_USER(usr_id)
);

CREATE TABLE BOOKS
(
    isbn varchar(17) not null primary key,
    title varchar(30) not null,
    number_of_copies int not null,
    Author varchar(30) not null,
    Number_of_pages int not null,
    publish_year int not null,
    book_type varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE DIGITAL_BOOKS
(
    digital_id int not null primary key,
    format varchar(30) not null,
    size_mb int not null,
    digital_isbn varchar(17) not null,
    foreign key(digital_isbn) references BOOKS(isbn)
);

CREATE TABLE PHYSICAL_BOOKS
(
    physical_id int not null primary key,
    condition varchar(20) not null,
    physical_isbn varchar(17) not null,
    foreign key(physical_isbn) references BOOKS(isbn)
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK_COPY
(
    digi_id int not null,
    phys_id int not null,
    primary key(digi_id, phys_id),
    foreign key(digi_id) references DIGITAL_BOOKS(digital_id),
    foreign key(phys_id) references PHYSICAL_BOOKS(physical_id)
);

CREATE TABLE CONTNS
(
    trans_id int not null primary key,
    digi_id int not null,
    phys_id int not null,
    foreign key(digi_id) references BOOK_COPY(digi_id),
    foreign key(phys_id) references BOOK_COPY(phys_id)
);
```

Despite me being able to look and see that `digi_id` and `phys_id` are in fact primary keys of the `book_copy` table, I keep getting this error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 66
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'BOOK_COPY' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__CONTNS__digi_id__37A5467C'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 66
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Am I missing something obvious? I'm just starting out with using this program, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A FK must reference the whole key, i.e. both PK columns digi_id, phys_id here.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean

Comment: Make life easier for everyone. What does the name "CONTNS" mean? Nothing to me. And why do you need to abbreviate, condense, or obfuscate the name itself? What exactly do you save by removing some vowels and letters? More importantly, I think your schema is logically flawed and that is part of your struggle. It seems you tried to implement a <type of> relationship between books and the 2 subtype tables but got confused and lost your way.

Comment: And I suggest that you may have many very different types of "transactions" that might be better implemented separately. Currently you have just begun to model a "borrow" transaction yet you chose to use very generic names. That is a form of premature optimization which can contribute to your confusion.

Comment: I would suggest you to first create tables, then PRIMARY Keys, then foreign keys. It will make things more clearer. Also, always name PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY. Don't go for system generated names

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTNS
(
    trans_id int not null primary key,
    digi_id int not null,
    phys_id int not null,
    foreign key(digi_id) references BOOK_COPY(digi_id),
    foreign key(phys_id) references BOOK_COPY(phys_id)
);
```

You are creating two foreign keys to parent table `BOOK_COPY`. But that table has a *compound* primary key (ie a multi-column primary key)

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK_COPY
(
    digi_id int not null,
    phys_id int not null,
    primary key(digi_id, phys_id),  --> here
    ...
)
```

As a consequence, you need a *compound* foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTNS
(
    trans_id int not null primary key,
    digi_id int not null,
    phys_id int not null,
    foreign key(digi_id, phys_id) references BOOK_COPY(digi_id, phys_id)
);
```